# Isomorphism of equivariant maps over real numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quaternions

Let $W$ be a real irreducible representation of finite group $G$. According to the Frobenius Theorem on real division algebra, $\text{End}_G(W)$ is isomorphic to either the field of real numbers, the field of complex numbers, or the division ring of quaternions.

I want to find an isomorphism in each case.

I have some ideas, which I wrote in the following. Please tell me whether they are correct and help me to find an isomorphism for the last case.

Let $\tau \in \operatorname{End}_G(W)$.
Case 1 ($\operatorname{End}_G(W) \cong \mathbb{R}$): By schure lemma, $\tau=\lambda \cdot 1_W$. So, $\lambda=\dfrac{\operatorname{trace}(\tau)}{\dim(W)}$. Consequently, $$\tau \mapsto \dfrac{\operatorname{trace}(\tau)}{\dim(W)}$$
is an isomorphism.

Case 2 ($\operatorname{End}_G(W) \cong \mathbb{C}$): I suspect $\tau$ has the matrix form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1& \lambda_2\\-\lambda_2 & \lambda_1 \end{bmatrix} \otimes I_{\frac{1}{2}\dim(W)}.
$$
So,
\begin{align} 
\lambda_1 &= \frac{\operatorname{trace}(\tau)}{\dim(W)} \\[4pt]
\lambda_2 &= \sqrt{{\operatorname{det}(\tau)}^{\frac{n}{2}} - 
\biggl(\frac{\operatorname{trace}(\tau)}{\dim(W)}\biggr)^2},
\end{align}
Consequently, $$\tau \mapsto \dfrac{\operatorname{trace}(\tau)}{\dim(W)}+i \sqrt{{\operatorname{det}(\tau)}^{\frac{n}{2}} - 
\biggl(\frac{\operatorname{trace}(\tau)}{\dim(W)}\biggr)^2}$$
is an isomorphism.

Case 3 ($\operatorname{End}_G(W) \cong \mathbb{H}$):
No idea